# Placing dlls in bin directory after successfull build

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I was working on a project , I needed to add a folder inside my application which consists some usefull dlls

[image]

under properties of my dll , I have changed the Copy to output directory field to copy always

On successfull build of my project I am getting the bin folder as :

[image]

After building the project I found out that  my dll is placed inside DLL folder 
but I do not want such folder , I want it to be inside the bin folder only , how can I achieve that.

Comment: Add a `bin` folder to either the classpath or build path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply delete the dll folder in both vs and the windows folder, then add them as references for your project and set there properties to copy always

you still may copy them manually the first time to make sure everything is going just fine

Answer (score 0):

IF the project has a reference to the DLL already VS will copy the dll to the bin folder.